# Is it OK to define a struct that inherit another one in extern "C" block?

Tags: c++

I wrap my C++ objects in C struct to expose them in pure interface. To simplify and reduce code, I write codes below. My question is that will the codes perform as expected? If not why ?

Thank you and best regards.

```cpp
// header file interface.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

typedef struct my_wrapper_t my_wrapper_t;

my_wrapper_t* my_wrapper_create();
void my_wrapper_destroy(my_wrapper_t* ptr);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// c++ file interface.cpp

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    ~Wrapper
    {
        if (rep)
        {
            delete rep;
        }
    }
    template <typename Derived, typename ...Args>
    static  Derived * create(Args ... args)
    {
        auto p = new Derived;
        p->rep = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return p;
    }
    T* rep;
}

extern "C"
{

struct my_wrapper_t : public Wrapper<Object>{}; // Object is c++ class define somewhere else

// implement interface as below
my_wrapper_t* my_wrapper_create()
{
    return Wrapper<my_wrapper_t>::create(...);
}
void my_wrapper_destroy(my_wrapper_t* ptr)
{
   delete ptr;
}


}
```

Codes above seems run well on my PC, but when I port it to Android, some bus rises, and I can't figure out why yet. Please help!

Comment: "some bus rises" - What does that mean? Please post the actual error message you get (*verbatim*). And please try posting [mcve]s, *not* just code snippets.

Comment: bus error -> you accessed a misaligned pointer; with the last fix to the code I am reasonably confident the bug is not in the code posted.

Comment: `extern "C"` means compile this code so that I can call its non-member functions from C"; it does **not** mean "compile this code as C". Yes, you can use inheritance, templates, etc. inside an `extern "C"` block. Whatever the problem is, it's something other than this.

Answer (score 1):

**Types** do not have [language linkage](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#1.sentence-1).  (Notionally their member *names* do, but it’s [always “C++”](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#4.sentence-6) and doesn’t matter.)

So there is nothing for a linkage specification to *do* with your `struct` definition and you can do what you like.  Obviously such a `struct` type can never be complete in C, but that also doesn’t matter.  The bus error arises elsewhere.